# how to send notification on socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, mern

I have an navbar in react.js which needs to be updated on sending message to the user (navbar given in the image):-
[image: navigation bar given in the photo below]

on receiving an message i want to update the message (the 0 in the icon in the navigation bar).

and here's my code :- 
on the front end in react :-

```
import React,{Component,Fragment} from 'react';
import {Collapse,Navbar,NavbarToggler,NavbarBrand,Nav,NavItem,NavLink,UncontrolledDropdown,
    DropdownToggle,
    DropdownMenu,
    DropdownItem,Badge } from 'reactstrap';
import '../Styles/Navbar.css';
import auth from '../../functions/isAuthenticated';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {faComments} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import signout from '../../functions/logoutFunction';
import {socket} from '../../functions/socket';
import decode from 'jwt-decode';
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard';
import Addskill from '../Skill/Addskill';
import axios from 'axios';

class Navigation extends Component{
    state={
        isOpen:false,
        message:0,
        status:''
    }
 constructor(props)
 {
     super(props);
     this.toggle=this.toggle.bind(this);
     this.socket=socket;
     this.socket.on('newmessage',(data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        let {message}=this.state;
        this.setState({message:message+1});
    });
 }
 UNSAFE_componentWillMount()
 {

 }
 componentDidMount()
 {
     if(auth.isAuthenticated())
     {
        const token=decode(localStorage.getItem('token'));
        const id=token.id;
        axios.get('/user/'+id).then(res=>{
            this.setState({
                status:res.data.user.Status
            });
        }).catch(err=>{

        });


     }

 }
 toggle()
{
    this.setState({
        isOpen:!this.state.isOpen
    });
}
userSingout(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    signout();
    window.location='/login';

}
render()
{
    let {status,message}=this.state;
    return(
        <div>
        <Navbar color='light' light expand='sm'>
        <NavbarBrand href='/' >Amberlit</NavbarBrand>
        <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
        <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
        <Nav className='ml-auto' navbar>
        {auth.isAuthenticated() ? <Fragment>
            <NavItem>

        <NavLink href=''><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faComments} size='2x'></FontAwesomeIcon><Badge pill>{message}</Badge></NavLink>
                </NavItem>

            <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
            <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                Profile
            </DropdownToggle>
            <DropdownMenu right>
                <DropdownItem >
                 <NavLink href='/profile'>{(status==='true') ? 'Update Info':'Complete Info'}</NavLink>
                </DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem>
                  <NavLink href='/skill'>{(status==='true')?'Update Skills':'Add Skills'}</NavLink>
                </DropdownItem>
            </DropdownMenu>
            </UncontrolledDropdown> 
            <NavItem>
                <NavLink href='/dashboard'>Dashboard</NavLink>
            </NavItem>



            <NavItem>
            <NavLink onClick={this.userSingout}>Logout</NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            </Fragment>:<Fragment><NavItem>
             <NavLink href='/register'>Sign Up</NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
            <NavLink href='/login'>Sign In</NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            </Fragment>}
        </Nav>
        </Collapse>

        </Navbar>
        </div>
    );
}
}
export default Navigation;
```

and this is my backend code :-

```
const io=require('../server.js').io;
const Message=require('../models/Message');
const shortid=require('shortid');
const sequelize=require('sequelize');
const Op=sequelize.Op;
module.exports=(socket)=>{

    socket.on('online',(data,callback)=>{
        const recieverId=data.id;
        Message.findAll({where:{recieverId}},{order:['senderId','DESC']}).then(result=>{
            socket.emit('useronline',{user:result});

        }).catch(err=>{
             callback(err);
        });
        callback();

    });
    socket.on('check',({senderId,recieverId},callback)=>{
        Message.findAll({where:{
            [Op.or]:[{senderId:senderId,recieverId:recieverId},{senderId:recieverId,recieverId:senderId}]}},{order:'DESC'}).then(
            result=>{
                socket.emit('message',{message:result});
            }
        ).catch(err=>{
            callback(err);
        });

    });
    socket.on('messagesent',(data)=>{
        let room
        const {senderId,recieverId,senderName,recieverName,message,mid}=data;
        Message.findOne({where:{
           [Op.or]:[{senderId:senderId,recieverId:recieverId},{senderId:recieverId,recieverId:senderId}]
        }}).then(result=>{
               if(result)
               {
                   room=result.room;
                   let senddata={
                       senderId:senderId,
                       recieverId:recieverId,
                       senderName:senderName,
                       recieverName:recieverName,
                       Message:message,
                       room:room,
                       mid:mid
                   }
                   Message.create({
                    senderId:senderId,
                    recieverId:recieverId,
                    senderName:senderName,
                    recieverName:recieverName,
                    Message:message,
                    room:room,
                    mid:mid

                }).then(()=>{
                    socket.to(recieverId).emit('newmessage',senddata);
                    socket.emit('newmessage',senddata);
                    console.log('message sent');
                }).catch(err=>{
                    console.log(err);
                });
               }
               else
               {
                  room=shortid.generate();
                  const {senderId,recieverId,senderName,recieverName,message,mid}=data;
                  Message.create({
                    senderId:senderId,
                    recieverId:recieverId,
                    senderName:senderName,
                    recieverName:recieverName,
                    Message:message,
                    room:room,
                    mid:mid

                  }).then(result=>{
                    socket.to(recieverId).emit('newmessage',data);
                  }).catch(err=>{
                     console.log(err);
                  });
               }
        }).catch(err=>{
               console.log(err);
        });

    });
    socket.on('disconnect',(socket)=>{
        //socket.disconnect();
    });
}
```

can anyone tell me how to update the message notification on receiving new message ?